# How to push data to a SharePoint list without using a form?

Tags: powerapps

I have a collection that is created programmatically. How do I push this collection into a SharePoint list without using a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Patch function to complete this task.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-patch